# A simple python program template is required (a + b)

Tags: python, templates

Given the numbers a and b. You need to find their amount and print it.
Please provide a template for such a program in python.

Answer (score 2):

Basically we need to figure out if there exists an integer `k` such that, for all `i`,

```
k mod l[i] = d[i],
```

and it is given that the sum of `l[i]` is `n`. We know from number theory the useful fact that if `l[i] = f * g` and `f` and `g` are relatively prime, then the equation

```
k mod l[i] = d[i]
```

is equivalent to the equations

```
k mod f = d[i] mod f
k mod g = d[i] mod g.
```

Our goal, then, is to factor the `d[i]` into prime powers and verify that the system of equations is solvable for each prime power.

---

To factor the `l[i]` in time `O(n)`, we can just use trial division, since the running time will be on the order of

```
sum_i √l[i] ≤ sum_i l[i] = n.
```

The only other piece is combining two equations

```
k mod p^e = r
k mod p^f = s
```

for some variable `k` and given prime `p`, exponents `e ≥ f`, and residues `r` and `s`. Since `p^f|p^e`, this is easy. We just verify that `r mod p^f = s` (for consistency) and then the second equation is redundant. If we reach a single prime power equation without uncovering an inconsistency, then the system is solvable with respect to this prime power.